# XCode 4 - IPhone Dev - Good Debug Tutorial

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, xcode4.3

I'm beginning IPhone development with XCode 4 and Objectiv-C. Since I think strong debug and IDE knowledge is required to master a language, I'm looking for good resources about the debugging process and XCode.

A problem I faced recently was that, an unknownException was being thrown in a sample code and I couldn't know how to debug it, since it crashed right after jumping into my Main. I think with a better configuration, it would have been much easier to debug !

I've already found this resource : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

But I couldn't find something related to debug in there... Did I miss something ?

Comment: Since you are a beginner, debugging will not help you much (well, it will, but, believe me, not in the way you expect it). Just try coding more accurate.

Comment: I'm not new to coding, I'm new to XCode, Objectiv-C (even tho I got C++ and C# background)... I use debugging as a help to understand how things works next to my more scholar way of learning (books, samples)...

Comment: And how can Andy become more 'accurate' without obtaining any information on the nature of the errors in his code ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, if you see the difference between "no errors by accurate coding" and "no errors by debugging and clearing bugs", you will understand my position.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea : I do get your point but, I'm the kind of developper that can make a mistake in one on million of lines of code and when that happens, I have to admit I love a little help from my best friend, Mr. Debugger :)

Comment: Ok, @Andy M, I also got to your point )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy, this first is about super basic debugging: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/xcode-debugging_iphone-sdk/

And here you can find two excellent tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Easy to make mistakes in Objective-C...

1. Not having a view attached to your view controller
2. Sending a message to a deallocated instance. Turn on NSZombieEnabled.
3. Forgot to add the Framework (e.g. MapKit)

If the crash isn't fixed at this point. Set a breakpoint in your app delegate and just step through every line until it crashes. Move the breakpoint up, run again, and inspect the values.

Comment: That's exactely the mistake I made by removing links all around my sample code trying to get how everything was built. I didn't know "NSZombieEnabled" but it's exactely what I'm looking for ! Simple tips that can improve highly the debugging and coding experience, thanks a whole lot !

Comment: Are there downsides in turning on NSZombieEnabled all the time ? Why don't they enable it by default ? Should I switch it on only when I want to debug something ?

Comment: NSZombieEnabled basically means the object isn't released. It is marked released but the object is kept around so that when you accidentally send messages you get more than a crash to a deallocated object reference.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a list of what they consider to be the best debugging tricks for iOS [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html).

There is also a couple of videos on the developer's site. I can never find out how to make a direct link, but there aren't that many videos, so just search for "debug":

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

There is also one from last year:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Access to the developer site requires registration.

Should you ever consider venturing into OS X territory, then here is the Apple-approved [debugging magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html).