# iphone - how to understand crash logs on device

Tags: iphone, logging, crash, organizer

I have this logs of a crash that seems to be connected to a mkmapview and the auto lock of my device (1 min):

T

```
hread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b6bd350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b63411e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b67096e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac0ed4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac0bff4 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1bfa74 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac0c078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac0c110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac0d594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b1bf9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33460f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33460d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x370242e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x353762fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  FT105RF                         0x0007cbb8 main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b5f6b1c start + 0
```

Can someone helps me to understand which lines of logs can be helpful for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you may find some useful answers here:

[XCode 4 - IPhone Dev - Good Debug Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540696/xcode-4-iphone-dev-good-debug-tutorial)

reading the lines you show is not the easiest and most convenient way of debugging, so these tutorials might help you doing it another way.

hope i helped

Comment: Thank you. One question. If I use arc project I don't have to dealloc/release mkmapview....right?

Comment: i'm not very experienced with that, so I'm nut sure, but I believe not no. Hope I helped you.

Comment: one other tip which really helped me with debugging: add breakpoints. if you add one every action your app performs, you will see where you app gets stuck, and try to improve that code.

Comment: sorry to say but I've never heard of NSSZombies. good luck debugging!